# Between windowDidMove and windowWillMove

Tags: cocoa

I've been trying with windowDidMove and windowWillMove (NSWindowDelegate) but I think I need something between these two...

Is there any other way to detect when I move my window in cocoa?
I mean - I want to trigger a function if I drag a window to the bottom of the screen, but I want this function to be run even if I didn't yet release the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The middle ground you are seeking is handling the mouse events yourself and implementing the window dragging. If you do this you determine how dragging works; so you can constrain the window to an area of the screen, trigger events when the window reaches a screen edge, etc.

You'll need to do some reading, you could start with [Apple's *Handling Mouse Events*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingMouseEvents/HandlingMouseEvents.html).

If you have problems once you've done the reading, written some code, etc. ask a new question, showing your code, and explain the problem you've hit. Somebody will probably help you out.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I'm new to programming and even newer to cocoa. I'm trying to write something that will help me in future work!